# Undefined_constant: Error after PHP 7 upgrade

Tags: php, random, random-seed

I have this simple PHP script (authors.php) to rotate through a list of images in a random order

```
<?php 
$random = mt_rand(1,9);
$image_1 = '<img src="/gallery/authors/1.jpg">';
$image_2 = '<img src="/gallery/authors/2.jpg">';
$image_3 = '<img src="/gallery/authors/3.jpg">';
$image_4 = '<img src="/gallery/authors/4.jpg">';
$image_5 = '<img src="/gallery/authors/5.jpg">';
$image_6 = '<img src="/gallery/authors/6.jpg">';
$image_7 = '<img src="/gallery/authors/7.jpg">';
$image_8 = '<img src="/gallery/authors/8.jpg">';
$image_9 = '<img src="/gallery/authors/9.jpg">';
echo ${image_.$random};
?>
```

It was working fine until I upgraded from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2.34.

Now I get this error.

```
Use of undefined constant image_ - assumed 'image_' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/website/public_html/authors.php, line 12
```

What needs to be changed in order for this script to work?

Thanks

Comment: use: `echo ${'image_' . $random};` that should [work](https://3v4l.org/pY8Hv)

Comment: Also use array to store authors.

Comment: `$image = '<img src="/gallery/authors/' . $random . '.jpg">';`

Comment: Is there any advantage to creating all the different variables? Why not just create the single string and then concatenate the random number.  Are you doing anything with the variables later on?

Comment: Lol, 15 seconds too late @Cid next time I won't take a breath :-)

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies.
The first reply by @berend solved my issue. Although the other answers seem simpler and usable, I would gladly award the Right Answer to berend :)

Comment: You should, IMHO, accept the answer by @Jerson! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of long,long lines

```
$random = mt_rand(1,9);
echo "<img src=\"/gallery/authors/{$random}.jpg\">";
```